# Convert Anonymous Inner Method to Lambda in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

How can I convert the following code (specifically the public void run() method) into a lambda using Java 8?

```
public class SampleApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Hello " + i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        t1.start();
    }
}
```

Tried:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() -> {

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println("Hello " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };

);
```

But Eclipse keeps throwing errors...

Comment: Remove the `new Runnable`.

Comment: BTW: just because you can use lambdas does not mean you have to use them. I find it much more readable to use method handles. Thats generally a good idea if the lambda is longer than 2 lines.

Answer (score 8):

Simply remove the `new Runnable`:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> { /* body */ });
```

You might want to consider pulling that body out into a "real" method, and using a method reference instead:

```
static void doSomething() { /* body */ }

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread t1 = new Thread(SampleApp::doSomething);
}
```

Big lambda bodies are not especially readable.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you want it inline you can do this

```
    final Thread t1 = new Thread(()->{
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + i);
            try { Thread.sleep(100); }
            catch (final InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class SampleApp  {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Thread( ()-> {
            IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i +1).limit(10).forEach(i->{
                System.out.println("Hello " + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
            
        }).start();
        }}
```